# how get all the data from json file using foreach in laravel?

Tags: html, json, laravel

My laravel controller

```
   public function index()
    { 
    $get=Storage::disk('public')>get('Philippines.json');
    $json = json_decode($get, true); 
           
    return view('BarangayFolder.index')>with('json',$json);
```

the output i'm trying to achieve on my option tag is something like this;

```
    "BANI"
    "BUYON"
    "CABARUAN"
    "CABULALAAN"
    "CABUSLIGAN"
    "CALIOET-LIBONG"
    "CASILIAN"
    "COROCOR"
```

i'cant figure out how to get all the of "barangay_list" data, i tried many solution and ideas but still not getting it.

```
{
      "01": {
        "region_name": "REGION 1",
        "province_list": {
          "ILOCOS NORTE": {
            "municipality_list": {
              "ADAMS": {
                "barangay_list": [
                  "ADAMS (POB.)"
                ]
              },
              "BACARRA": {
                "barangay_list": [
                  "BANI",
                  "BUYON",
                  "CABARUAN",
                  "CABULALAAN",
                  "CABUSLIGAN",
                  "CADARATAN"
                ]
      }

}
```

i managed to get thedata of "region_name" which is "REGION 1" but i can't get the data of barangay_list.

```
<datalist id="datalist-content"> 
      foreach (array($json['01']) as $data)
            <option value="{{$data['region_name']}}"></option>
      endforeach
</datalist>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand your json file to get proper data.

You want data of **barangay_list**. If we create a tree of your data it should look like following:

```
-01
--province_list
----->ILOCOS NORTE
----------->municipality_list
------------------>BACARRA
--------------------->barangay_list
```

Either you can use

```
foreach ($json['01']['province_list']['ILOCOS NORTE']['municipality_list']['BACARRA']['barangay_list'] as $data)
     <option value="{{$data}}"></option>
endforeach
```

or you can first save you list in variable and use it in loop

```
@php
       $barangay_list = $json['01']['province_list']['ILOCOS NORTE']['municipality_list']['BACARRA']['barangay_list'];
@endphp
@foreach ($barangay_list as $data)
         <option value="{{$data}}"></option>
@endforeach
```

You have used true with json_decode that will convert data into array so you dont need to add array function to convert in array.

Answer (score 1):

your loop is not proper try with below code

```
<datalist id="datalist-content"> 
             foreach (array($json['01']['province_list']['ILOCOS NORTE']['municipality_list']['BACARRA']['barangay_list']) as $data)
              <option value="{{$data}}">{{$data}}</option>
             endforeach
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea sir sandy, it works well now after removing the array inside foreach.